# How do I reference the last character of a string without using variable_name.at()?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, reference

the code that I'm currently working with looks like this:

```
if ((text.at(text.size() -1 ) != '!' ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != '?') && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != ':' ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != ',' ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != ';' ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != '=' ) )
```

The details of it aren't terribly important but I'm basically trying to make a kind of word processor that only uses the command prompt, and whenever the user presses enter with nothing in the input buffer, the program closes because it's being terminated in "an unusual way" which I'm taking to mean that this line of code is trying to reference a position in the string that doesn't exist, i.e. -1. So I need a new way to reference the last character in a given string variable that can still work with the line of code given. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check for `!text.empty()` first.

Comment: `string::at()` also throws an [`out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception if you try to go beyond its bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check `text` is not empty before access its element and use [std::string::rbegin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) or [std::string::back(needs C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) to simplify your code.

you call it this way:

```
if (!text.empty())
{
    char c = *text.rbegin();
    if (c != '!' && 
        c != '?' && 
        c != ':' && 
        c != ',' && 
        c != ';' && 
        c != '=' )
    {
    }
}
```

To enhance code readability, you could introduce a local variable in this situation, it's cheap to make a copy of a char and you can shorten your `if` statement a lot.

Comment: Thanks a bunch but when I try to compile this code, i get the error "'rbegin' was not declared in this scope". Is there a library that I need to declare prior to using this function other than <string>?

Comment: you call lit this: `*text.rbegin() != '!'`, right? It doesn't need other lib

Comment: Ohh I see. I'm new to this, I was trying to something like `(text.at(rbegin()) != '!' )`. Cheers for the help!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Did I miss something?

Comment: Before, he was using `at` on an empty string, and getting an exception.  You've simply modified it to dereference an invalid iterator, leading to undefined behavior.  He probably thinks the problem is solved, because the program isn't crashing, because instead of an exception, he's getting undefined behavior.

Comment: @that's true, I wrote another if/else then edited it away. let me edit the answer.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this fix needs an asterisk before text, for it to work? It does work for me and that's great, I'd like to understand why that happens though.

Comment: @user2779581 I didn't add asterisk. rbegin returns a reference to last element, you need to dereference it. that's why there is asterisk. I added `if (!text.empty())`

Comment: And is this the right iteration now? I'm hearing discord in the comments lol.

Comment: @user2779581: It should be noted that there was nothing wrong with the way you were using the `at` function.  The only problem with your original code was failure to check whether the string was empty first.

Comment: Oh ok, another person below noted that I just needed to check if the string was empty as well. I might just go back to using `at` then, I understand it more. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @user2779581 cheers. also read up http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string. to understand more regarding std::string

Answer (score 2):

Seems easy enough, just check for `text.size() > 0` first

```
if (text.size() > 0 && 
    text.at(text.size() - 1) != '!' && 
    text.at(text.size() - 1) != '?' && 
    text.at(text.size() - 1) != ':' && 
    text.at(text.size() - 1) != ',' && 
    text.at(text.size() - 1) != ';' && 
    text.at(text.size() - 1) != '=')
```

or maybe you intended this logic (it's not really clear from your question)

```
if (text.size() == 0 || 
    (text.at(text.size() - 1) != '!' && 
     text.at(text.size() - 1) != '?' && 
     text.at(text.size() - 1) != ':' && 
     text.at(text.size() - 1) != ',' && 
     text.at(text.size() - 1) != ';' && 
     text.at(text.size() - 1) != '='))
```

You should also simplify that expression, it's way too complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this should work as well. I it's crude but I'm just reading a book on how to code and was getting bored with the examples they were giving so I wanted to try something a bit different. I'm sure it will get better with time. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Actually this will really come in handy for translating new paragraphs, so you've answered a question that I probably just hadn't got around to answering yet :D